# how to configure database.yml in windows 7 to use postgis

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, postgis

My database.yml development section looks like this:

development:

```
  adapter: postgis
  encoding: unicode
  database: openData_development
  pool: 5
  username: postgres
  password: test1234
  schema_search_path: "public,postgis"
  script_dir: C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.2\share\contrib\postgis-2.0
```

rake db:create worked, the openData_development schema was created.
but i cant use postgis...

If i want to create a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE bezirks (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255),
    beznr integer,
    district_code integer,
    main_id integer NOT NULL,
    latlon geometry,
    CONSTRAINT enforce_dims_latlon CHECK ((st_ndims(latlon) = 2)),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_geotype_latlon CHECK (((geometrytype(latlon) = 'MULTIPOLYGON'::text) OR (latlon IS NULL))),
    CONSTRAINT enforce_srid_latlon CHECK ((st_srid(latlon) = 4326))
);
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR:  Type »geometry« doesnt exist
LINE 27:     latlon geometry,
```

Answer (score 1):

using the postgis adapter does not automagically install the postgis extensions on your db.

You have to do it yourself ; one solution to help automation of this is to create a 'bare' db on your server named 'template_postgis', install the postgis extensions on it as you would usually do (follow the installation guide on postgis website), and then add this to your database.yml:

```
development:
  template: template_postgis
```

do it on every dbs so rails will create them as a copy of this template.